# Unable to verify solution to difference equation $m_x - 2pqm_{x-2} = p^2 + q^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, recurrence-relations

I want to verify that the solution to the difference equation

$m_x - 2pqm_{x-2} = p^2 + q^2$

with boundary conditions

$m_0 = 0$

$m_1 = 0$

is

$$m_x = -\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2pq}} +1)(\sqrt{2pq})^x + \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2pq}} - 1)(-\sqrt{2pq})^x + 1$$

**General solution to inhomogeneous equation**

I know that that general solution for $m_x$ will be equal to the general solution to the homogeneous equation plus a particular solution to the inhomogeneous equation. So the general solution to the homogeneous equation

$m_x - 2pqm_{x-2} = 0$

ends up being

$m_x = A(\sqrt{2pq})^x + B(-\sqrt{2pq})^x$

Using $m_0 = 0$ we have that $A = -B$ giving us

$m_x = A(\sqrt{2pq})^x - A(-\sqrt{2pq})^x$

Using $m_1 = 0$ we have that

$0 = -B(\sqrt{2pq}) + B(-\sqrt{2pq})$

$0 = -B(\sqrt{2pq}) - B(\sqrt{2pq})$

$0 = -2B(\sqrt{2pq})$

$=> B = -A = 0$

So I must have done something wrong? And where is the "$1$" at the end of the correct general solution above coming from? Can someone show how to verify the solution correctly?

Comment: My main point is that I want to know where I going wrong in deriving the general solution of the inhomogeneous equation. I appreciate the answers but I am not looking for alternative methods. I will be expected to derive such a solution in an upcoming exam.

Comment: Nevermind, I was applying the boundary conditions to the homogeneous equation when I should've been applying them to the inhomogeneous equation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as I suspect, $p+q=1$, one might prefer the general formula, valid for every integer $x\geqslant0$, $$m_{2x}=m_{2x+1}=1-(2pq)^x.$$ In the general case, if $2pq\ne1$, try $$m_{2x}=m_{2x+1}=\left(1-(2pq)^x\right)\,\frac{p^2+q^2}{1-2pq}.$$ Finally, if $2pq=1$, $$m_{2x}=m_{2x+1}=x\,(p^2+q^2).$$
In each case, checking that the recursion holds should be direct.

*Morality:* To transform the formula for $m_{2x}=m_{2x+1}$ into a single formula valid for every $m_x$, based on the oscillatory nature of $(-1)^x$, while always posssible, might not be a good idea.

Comment: Yes $p = 1 - q$, cheers for the alternative method but I really need to find where I am going wrong my workings above.

Comment: According to your later comment, now you found where you are going astray, or did you not?

Comment: Yes, I was applying the boundary conditions at the wrong stage.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Since you have the solution we can use the mathematical induction for verify the solution. Also $(-1)^x=(-1)^{x-2}, \forall x\in\mathbb{N}.$